# Maze traversal with recursion what prints every full path

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to traverse a maze and produce all valid paths. The maze always starts at S. All exits could be anywhere along the right-most
wall. The top wall and bottom walls are always solid rows of # symbols. I can only move through and adjacent square that contains a char that is not "#".

This is an example of a maze.

```
######
Sa#hln
#bdp##
##e#ko
#gfij#
######
```

This is what should be printed out:

S,a,b,d,e,f,i,j,k,o

S,a,b,d,p,h,l,n

But I get S,a,b,d,e,f,i,j,k,o,p,h,l,n

This is the first path, and the half of the second path where it forked. I would be grateful for any help. Thank you.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

//std::ifstream file("maze.txt");
string str;
string file_contents;
fstream in("maze.txt");

//check if char is not #
bool characterAt(string maze[][6], int r, int c){
    if (maze[r][c] == "#"){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
//check if I have been there before
bool backTrack(bool maze[][6], int r, int c){
    if (maze[r][c] == false){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//check if my move is in bounds.
bool validMove(int r, int c){
    if (r - 1 < 0 || r + 1 > 6 ||
        c - 1 < 0 || c + 1 > 6){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}`
//check if there is a next move
bool thereIsNextMove(string maze[][6], bool bmaze[][6], int rows, int columns){
    if (validMove(rows - 1, columns) && backTrack(bmaze, rows - 1, columns) && characterAt(maze, rows - 1, columns) ||
        validMove(rows + 1, columns) && backTrack(bmaze, rows + 1, columns) && characterAt(maze, rows + 1, columns) ||
        validMove(rows, columns - 1) && backTrack(bmaze, rows, columns - 1) && characterAt(maze, rows, columns - 1) ||
        validMove(rows, columns + 1) && backTrack(bmaze, rows, columns + 1) && characterAt(maze, rows, columns + 1)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
void generate_all_paths(string maze[][6], bool bmaze[][6], int rows, int columns){
    int y = rows;
    int x = columns;
    string path = maze[y][x];
    stack<string> s;
    if (thereIsNextMove(maze, bmaze, y, x) || x == 5){
        s.push(path);
        cout << s.top();
        s.pop();
    }

    if (validMove(y - 1, x) && characterAt(maze, y - 1, x) && backTrack(bmaze, y - 1, x)){
        bmaze[y][x] = true;
        generate_all_paths(maze, bmaze, y - 1, x);
    }
    if (validMove(y + 1, x) && characterAt(maze, y + 1, x) && backTrack(bmaze, y + 1, x)){
        bmaze[y][x] = true;
        generate_all_paths(maze, bmaze, y + 1, x);
    }

    if (validMove(y, x - 1) && characterAt(maze, y, x - 1) && backTrack(bmaze, y, x - 1)){
        bmaze[y][x] = true;
        generate_all_paths(maze, bmaze, y, x - 1);
    }
    if (validMove(y, x + 1) && characterAt(maze, y, x + 1) && backTrack(bmaze, y, x + 1)){
        bmaze[y][x] = true;
        generate_all_paths(maze, bmaze, y, x + 1);
    }
}



int main(){
    while (getline(in, str))
    {
        file_contents += str;
        //file_contents.push_back('\n');
    }
    string maze[6][6];
    for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++){
            char mazeChar = file_contents.at(6 * row + col);
            maze[row][col] = mazeChar;
        }
    }
    bool bmaze[6][6];
    for (int brow = 0; brow < 6; brow++){
        for (int bcol = 0; bcol < 6; bcol++){
            bmaze[brow][bcol] = false;
        }
    }
    string path;
    generate_all_paths(maze, bmaze, 1, 0);
    int age;
    cin >> age;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the stack inside 'generate_all_paths' function has not been used at all. In the given implementation that stack contains at most one element at any given time. Instead of printing the path every time you find one, just keep the stack global and push the new path to it then print the entire stack at once when you reach the destination then just remove the element from the stack at the end of the function, like how you would walk back to the fork point, if you are actually traversing the maze.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

//std::ifstream file("maze.txt");
string str;
string file_contents;
fstream in("maze.txt");
stack<string> s;
//check if char is not #
bool characterAt(string maze[][6], int r, int c){
    if (maze[r][c] == "#"){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
//check if I have been there before
bool backTrack(bool maze[][6], int r, int c){
    if (maze[r][c] == false){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//check if my move is in bounds.
bool validMove(int r, int c){
    if (r - 1 < 0 || r + 1 > 6 ||
        c - 1 < 0 || c + 1 > 6){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
//check if there is a next move
bool thereIsNextMove(string maze[][6], bool bmaze[][6], int rows, int columns){
    if (validMove(rows - 1, columns) && backTrack(bmaze, rows - 1, columns) && characterAt(maze, rows - 1, columns) ||
        validMove(rows + 1, columns) && backTrack(bmaze, rows + 1, columns) && characterAt(maze, rows + 1, columns) ||
        validMove(rows, columns - 1) && backTrack(bmaze, rows, columns - 1) && characterAt(maze, rows, columns - 1) ||
        validMove(rows, columns + 1) && backTrack(bmaze, rows, columns + 1) && characterAt(maze, rows, columns + 1)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
template < typename T > void print( const std::stack<T>& stk )
{
    struct cheat : std::stack<T> { using std::stack<T>::c ; } ;
    const auto& seq = static_cast< const cheat& >(stk).c ;

    for( const auto& v : seq ) std::cout << v << ' ' ;
    std::cout << '\n' ;
}
void generate_all_paths(string maze[][6], bool bmaze[][6], int rows, int columns){
    int y = rows;
    int x = columns;
    string path = maze[y][x];
    bool pushed = false;
    if (thereIsNextMove(maze, bmaze, y, x)){
        s.push(path);
        pushed = true;
    }
    if (x == 5){
        s.push(path);
        pushed=true;
        print(s);//printing the entire stack once a path has been found
    }

    if (validMove(y - 1, x) && characterAt(maze, y - 1, x) && backTrack(bmaze, y - 1, x)){
        bmaze[y][x] = true;
        generate_all_paths(maze, bmaze, y - 1, x);
    }
    if (validMove(y + 1, x) && characterAt(maze, y + 1, x) && backTrack(bmaze, y + 1, x)){
        bmaze[y][x] = true;
        generate_all_paths(maze, bmaze, y + 1, x);
    }

    if (validMove(y, x - 1) && characterAt(maze, y, x - 1) && backTrack(bmaze, y, x - 1)){
        bmaze[y][x] = true;
        generate_all_paths(maze, bmaze, y, x - 1);
    }
    if (validMove(y, x + 1) && characterAt(maze, y, x + 1) && backTrack(bmaze, y, x + 1)){
        bmaze[y][x] = true;
        generate_all_paths(maze, bmaze, y, x + 1);
    }
    if(pushed){
        s.pop();//removing the element from the stack like how you walk back to fork point
    }
}



int main(){
    while (getline(in, str))
    {
        file_contents += str;
        //file_contents.push_back('\n');
    }
    string maze[6][6];
    for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++){
            char mazeChar = file_contents.at(6 * row + col);
            maze[row][col] = mazeChar;
        }
    }
    bool bmaze[6][6];
    for (int brow = 0; brow < 6; brow++){
        for (int bcol = 0; bcol < 6; bcol++){
            bmaze[brow][bcol] = false;
        }
    }
    string path;
    generate_all_paths(maze, bmaze, 1, 0);
    int age;
    cin >> age;
    return 0;
}
```

PS - I had added a function named print just to print the stack